# C# Developing a Desktop Session Timer

Tags: c#, sql, windows, client-server

I would like to get some suggestions for a project i am working on.  Currently I have 12 computers joined to an AD domain using the same user to login to Windows 10 computers.  I am trying to develop an app that will present a message and then log off the user at specified time.  I actually have developed that app and for the most part it works.  It even has the ability to allow an admin user to come over and change the time remaining.  A new requirement has me a little stumped.  The admin would like to login to a central computer and monitor the times of the 12 computers and be able to change the time from a central interface.  So I am banging my head trying to brainstorm ideas.  I decided to ask for help.  Here is what I have come up with.

1. Client/Server App development.  (would have to learn)
2. SQL table.  Desktop app updates and pulls data (I would think that would be a lot of unnecessary traffic.  Would have to determine how often that app Push/Pulls the data.
3. Update a local data file and have the Central Management push/pull to that file.  Same idea as SQL?
4. Use a 3rd party app.  (Costs and I also like to have flexibility and control)

Any suggestions would be great.  I have no problem learning something new however this has unfortunately become a priority request so time management is important.  For the most part I am looking for suggestions.

Thank you very much for your time.  This is honestly my first "question post".